# Drawing on image with matplotlib and opencv2, update image?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, draw

I'm attempting to draw a mask onto an image using matplotlib and opencv2, but overlaying the images in a matplotlib plot and then tracking mouse events. I currently can draw onto the image, but it does not update in the view.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

class Painter(object):

    def __init__(self, ax, img):
        self.showverts = True
        self.figure = plt.figure(1)
        self.button_pressed = False
        self.img = img
        self.brush_size = 50
        self.color = 255

        canvas = self.figure.canvas
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.button_release_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_move)

    def button_press_callback(self, event):
        if(event.button == 1):
            self.button_pressed = True
            x = int(math.floor(event.xdata))
            y = int(math.floor(event.ydata))
            cv2.circle(self.img, (x, y), int(self.brush_size / 2), (self.color, self.color, self.color), -1)
            #update the image

    def button_release_callback(self, event):
        self.button_pressed = False
        cv2.imwrite('test.png', self.img)

    def on_move(self, event):
        if(self.button_pressed):
            x = int(math.floor(event.xdata))
            y = int(math.floor(event.ydata))
            cv2.circle(self.img, (x, y), int(self.brush_size / 2), (self.color, self.color, self.color), -1)
            #update the image

def draw_demo():
    imgOver = np.zeros((717,1465,3), np.uint8)
    imgMain = mpimg.imread('zebra.png')
    #imgMain = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(500, 500))

    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(imgMain, interpolation='nearest', alpha=1)
    ax.imshow(imgOver, interpolation='nearest', alpha=0.6)

    pntr = Painter(ax, imgOver)
    plt.title('Click on the image to draw')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    draw_demo()
```

How can I update the image on the pyplot as I draw on top of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a kind of hacky answer but it works for me so I thought you could give it a try.  The idea is to just delete the top item on the subplot's image stack and redraw it with the updated image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

class Painter(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, img):
        self.showverts = True
        self.figure = plt.figure(1)
        self.button_pressed = False
        self.img = img
        self.brush_size = 50
        self.ax = ax
        self.color = 255

        canvas = self.figure.canvas
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.button_release_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_move)

    def button_press_callback(self, event):
        if(event.button == 1):
            self.button_pressed = True
            x = int(math.floor(event.xdata))
            y = int(math.floor(event.ydata))
            cv2.circle(self.img, (x, y), int(self.brush_size / 2), (self.color, self.color, self.color), -1)
            #update the image

    def button_release_callback(self, event):
        self.button_pressed = False
        self.ax.images.pop()
        self.ax.imshow(self.img, interpolation='nearest', alpha=0.6)
        plt.draw()
        cv2.imwrite('test.png', self.img)

    def on_move(self, event):
        if(self.button_pressed):
            x = int(math.floor(event.xdata))
            y = int(math.floor(event.ydata))
            cv2.circle(self.img, (x, y), int(self.brush_size / 2), (self.color, self.color, self.color), -1)
            #update the image

def draw_demo():
    global imgMain
    imgOver = np.zeros((717,1465,3), np.uint8)
    imgMain = mpimg.imread('zebra.png')
    #imgMain = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(500, 500))

    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(imgMain, interpolation='nearest', alpha=1)
    ax.imshow(imgOver, interpolation='nearest', alpha=0.6)

    pntr = Painter(ax, imgOver)
    plt.title('Click on the image to draw')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    draw_demo()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call plt.draw() every time you update the image.

Comment: When I do that I get the error `QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I remembered incorrectly.  You call draw not show for updates.

Comment: Using `plt.draw()` also does not update the image. I believe that updates the plot, which I do not have.

Comment: `canvas.draw()` or `plt.gcf().canvas.draw()` to update the plot. But you need to update the data in the plot also.